# mongo : get one attribute from a

Tags: php, mongodb, shell

in mongo shell or PHP 
how do I retreive the "list" attribute of this document ?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51b972ebe4b075a9690bbc5b"),
"list" : [
"Environnement",
"Toutes thÃ©matiques",
"Transports"]
}
```

I'm looking how to do 
db.tags.list would return all the 'list' attributes of documents in mycollection

The answer was : 
db.tags.findOne().list

Comment: `$doc['list']` will do it

Comment: Yes, like Sammaye said... also if you've a more structured object you can acces with points like $doc["list.someotherstuff"]

Comment: `db.collection.find({'willy': 'wonka'})[0].hat_color`

Answer (score 1):

If you need all of the `list` attributes across *all* documents in the `tags` collection, you may want to use the [db.collection.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method ([MongoCollection::find()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) in PHP).

```
$tags = array();

foreach ($collection->find() as $document) {
    if (empty($document['list'] || ! is_array($document['list'])) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($document['list'] as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag;
    }
}
```

Offhand, if these documents had other fields that you didn't need, you could use the second argument to provide a projection to `find()` and limit the fields returned. In this case, `{ list: 1 }` would do it.

Taking this a step further, if you wanted to quickly retrieve all of the unique tags across the `list` fields in the collection's documents, you could use the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct) database command ([MongoCollection::distinct()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php) in PHP.

Assuming the collection had the following documents:

```
> db.foo.insert({x:['a','b','c']})
> db.foo.insert({x:['a','c','d']})
```

The following method would execute the `distinct` database command and return the array `[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]`:

```
$uniqueTags = $collection->distinct('list');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your document directly:

```
document['list']
```

If you are accessing a collection:

```
db.collection.findOne({_id: ObjectId("51b972ebe4b075a9690bbc5b")}).list
```

Comment: *Say that for the first case you had: var document = { "_id" : ObjectId("51b972ebe4b075a9690bbc5b"), "list" : [ "Environnement", "Toutes thÃ©matiques", "Transports"] }